# Adding multiple .c files in xcode

Tags: c, xcode, file

So I am just starting to learn C by following "Programming in C". I tried to add multiple files in the same project directory in xcode but I kept getting build errors. So I tried following this guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613463/xcode-4-4-1-c-programming-adding-new-c-files) but this doesn't work either.

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ryPq.jpg)

Note here that I run my file 'main c' successfully (it prints the correct output) and its target membership is 'Programming in C'

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KQo7.jpg)

In this picture, for the main.c file under 'test3', I have its target membership set as 'Test 3' but when I run the program, the output it gives me is the output from the 'main.c' file from 'Programming in C'. Why is that and how can I fix it? I'm interested in having multiple .c files under the same project if possible.

Answer (score 0):

In both pictures you seem to have "Programming in C" as the active target (the "Programming in C > My Mac 64-bit" menu) so that is what will be built and run. Try to change to "Test 3".

Comment: Your welcome and don't feel dumb Xcode takes some time to figure out